# Difference between totalJSHeapSize and usedJSHeapSize

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I was going over the JS [performance.memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/memory) documentation to understand the system load our web application is using.

The API returns the following values, explained in MDN as

`jsHeapSizeLimit`

```
The maximum size of the heap, in bytes, that is available to the context.
```

`totalJSHeapSize`

```
The total allocated heap size, in bytes.
```

`usedJSHeapSize`

```
The currently active segment of JS heap, in bytes.
```

I am not able to understand what is the difference between totalHeapSize and usedJSHeapsize.

specifically, what is the currently active segment JS heap and what is the allocated heap size?

Eg,

```
jsHeapSizeLimit : 4294705152
totalJSHeapSize : 308498771
usedJSHeapSize  : 267867563
```

Here jsHeapSizeLimit is around 4GB. I am guessing that is the memory that is free in my laptop which I can confirm with the task manager or Activity monitor.

But I am not able similarly understand what are the other two metrics and how are they different.

Can someone please explain these terms with some practical examples?

Comment: Do you understand what the heap is, how it is used, and how garbage collection works?

Comment: yes. Heap is the section in RAM that is used to store the variables used inside the code. Some of the variables lose their scope and they need to removed out out of the heap section. So garbage collection does this work of figuring out the potentially inactive variables and removing those space from heap memory

Comment: Variables are mostly stored on the stack actually (unless closures are in play), the heap is mainly used for objects. But yes, that's the `usedJSHeapSize`. However, the space that was used for things which are now inactive is not handed back to the operating system, it stays allocated for the js engine which will immediately reuse it when new variables become active - that's the `totalJSHeapSize`.

Answer (score 1):

- `totalJSHeapSize` is the total amount of memory allocated for the JavaScript heap, regardless of whether that memory is currently being used or not.
- `usedJSHeapSize` is the amount of memory within the JavaScript heap that is actively being utilized by objects and data in your application.

And probably after you'll wonder what the difference is between `totalJSHeapSize` and `jsHeapSizeLimit`.

- so `jsHeapSizeLimit` is the maximum amount of memory that the JavaScript heap of a web application is allowed to consume.

The thing is that `usedJSHeapSize` is the memory that is being used right now, and the `totalJSHeapSize` is the allocated memory for usage, but if your usage hits this amount then the `totalJSHeapSize` increases, so you can use more of it. And the `jsHeapSizeLimit` you can't just go over it, it's against excessive memory usage that could impact the browser's stability.